# Displaying umask in symbolic and octal form, at the same time?

Tags: linux, centos, umask

I'm trying to display the umask in both octal and symbolic at the same time.  The command I'm using is `umask -S -O`, but it doesn't work. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work? (bash)

```
echo $(umask;umask -S)
```